# Environment.getProperty null - Spring-Boot Spring-Cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a controller autowired with `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`.

```
@Controller public class RegistrationController{

@Autowired (required=false)
private ServiceA serviceA;

@Autowired
Environment env;
```

The spring-boot module is configured with cloud-config-client.
It reads the configuration from the config-server on start-up.

The controller gets the value from the Environment in one of its method.

```
   Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("services.fixeddelay.val"));
```

But when I refresh via the refresh endpoint `/refresh` , it gets null for the property from environment.

After a couple of refresh it gets the value. 
Is there a problem with autowiring this way? Should I use `@RefreshScope` here ? How it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the property `spring.application.name` in the configuration loaded from the config-server. The property was given in config-server by mistake, though it had a proper value in `classpath:bootstrap.yml`.

After first refresh, the existing properties were cleared from the Environment.
After second refresh, the environment values were getting loaded.

Removing the property `spring.application.name` from the config-server property file fixed the issue. Now refresh works even without `@RefreshScope`